# Log name of Scenario when it starts

Tags: karate

Is there a way to get Karate to automatically print the name of each scenario as it is executed into the logs? We have a reasonably large suite that generates `~25MB` of log data in our Jenkins pipeline console output and sometimes it’s a little tricky trying to match a line where `com.intuit.karate` logs an `ERROR` to the failure summary at the end of the run. It is most likely possible to obtain the scenario name and `print()` it but that would mean adding code to many hundred scenarios which I’d like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the fix for [this issue](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/239) Karate will log the Scenario name (if not empty) along with any failure trace.

A beta version with this fix is available `0.6.1.2` it would be great if you can try it and confirm.

If you feel more has to be done, do open a ticket and we'll do our best to get this into the upcoming `0.6.2` release.

Comment: Fantastic, cheers Peter I'll give that a try and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Does the scenario name only get logged on failure and would you expect the scenario name to be logged inline with the requests / responses or in the Failed scenarios section at the end of a .feature file run?

Comment: e.g. 

T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running examples.ExamplesTest

*** Is there any way to get the Scenario name to be logged at this point? ***

15:52:26.232 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: production
15:52:26.664 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 
1 > GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/doesntexist
etc.

Comment: @Dunc I can see how that can be useful, I've also felt the pain of wading though large logs. BUT - have you ever tried the HTML reports as seen here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports - most teams use this, and troubleshooting is much easier. the main problem you must be facing is distinguishing between the parallel threads which the HTML solves. else please do open a feature request and I will look at options.

Comment: We have tried to use the HTML reports which for shorter runs are excellent - however the system we're testing has well over a thousand discreet scenario runs and they get very big very quickly and Chrome and even Firefox Quantum start to struggle : ) One side effect of the ease of use of Karate is that we've generated _way_ more tests (and as a result way better coverage) than earlier solutions - it's almost *too* good!

Comment: I should correct myself - we've tried the cucumber reports, not those linked. I'll add that to our build and give it a try. Anything that aids our ability to quickly diagnose faults is great.

Comment: @Dunc great. this short video shows what to expect: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/899671441221623809