# Print scenario name when running each scenario

Tags: api, karate

I want to print the name of each scenario as the test run. What can i call or do to get the name so that i can execute `* print <scenario_name>` ?

The answer for this post is exactly what i want to do: [Print scenario name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602953/how-to-get-name-of-scenario-in-cucumber-java) Is there a way to access the Scenario object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now this is not supported, but will be easy to add. But here's the question - is this just to help you make sense of the logs ? Because if you are not using the *Cucumber HTML report* yet, you should - and that's what most teams are using: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/899671441221623809

Refer to this discussion for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47555173/143475

If you still really need this, kindly raise a feature request.

Edit: this will be available in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/257